# how to redirect a page which creates a popup, from that created popup using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-selectors

I am new to jQuery. I have a button on main page of my web application which creates a login pop. If user enters correct password then popup should be disappeared and the page which create that popup should go to welcome page of that user. I know how to disappear the popup if user enters correct password. How can I tell the explorer window which created that popup to go to the welcome page? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is that a popup, like a modal popup, or a popup like a bad, awful late 90s popup?

Comment: i created that popup using this function:                function popitup(url) {
    newwindow=window.open(url,'name', 'width=656,height=443');
    if (window.focus) {newwindow.focus()}
    return false;
   }   any other way to make a fancy popup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe with Javascript you can redirect the parent window with:

```
window.opener.location.href = <your url>;
```

And then simply close your popup:

```
window.close();
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need jQuery for this. Some simple JavaScript should do the trick.

```
//reload the parent window
//window.opener.location.reload();

//to change the parent window location
window.opener.location.href = "welcome.htm";    

//close the current window
self.close();
```

Comment: Sorry, I thought you wanted to reload the page. Edited my answer.